# how execute following js function when useEffect() function call in reactJS redux

Tags: react-redux

```
*//Listning mqtt messages* 
 


   window.HeartBeat.onMessageFunc = function (topic, message) {    
     console.log(topic +":"+ message.toString() );     
 };
```

*//Listning mqtt messages      host*

```
 window.HeartBeat.start("ws://3.18.215.###:8083/mqtt/","admin","public")
```

*//Subscribing*

```
 window.HeartBeat.subscribe("customer-permissions", function(payload){
   console.info(payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling these Methods inside a component then you can setState i.e

```
const [subscribed, setSubscribed] = React.useState(false)
```

when you get response 200 from server

and than

```
useEffact(() => {
  if(subscribed){
  //write your next logic here
 }
},[subscribed])
```

is should be an arrow function,
like

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(topic+":"+message.toString());
   window.HeartBeat.start("ws://3.18.215.137:8083/mqtt/",
    "admin","public")
    window.HeartBeat.subscribe("customer- 
    permissions",function(payload)
    setSubscribed(true)
   }
```

Your button should be

```
<button onClick = {() => handleButtonClick} > Button </button>
```

Comment: how i execute this code at same time like following,,    btn1.onclick = function(){
             window.HeartBeat.onMessageFunc = function (topic, message) {
                 console.log(topic+":"+message.toString());      
             };
  window.HeartBeat.start("ws://3.18.215.137:8083/mqtt/","admin","public")  
             
            window.HeartBeat.subscribe("customer-permissions",function(payload){
                         
            });
         }